# DirectX vertex buffer Default vs Default + Staging

Tags: c++, directx-11

I was searching for the difference between these two in terms of GPU reading speed and occasionally CPU writing(less then once per frame or even only once). I don't want to use `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` cause data will not be updated >= once per frame.
*Is there a significant performance increase with `Default + Staging` combo over the `Default` buffer?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best performance advice for Direct3D 11 here is actually the same as Direct3D 10.0. Start by reviewing this talk [Windows to Reality: Getting the Most out of Direct3D 10 Graphics in Your Games](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/4/a04deeb2-d7e2-42a5-984a-9ea5c92bfeb2/Windows%20to%20Reality%20-%20Getting%20the%20Most%20out%20of%20Direct3D%2010%20Graphics%20in%20your%20Games.zip) from Gamefest 2007.

To your question, any updates to a resource (texture or buffer) will have some potential performance impact due, but for 'occasional' updates, the best option is to use a STAGING resource and then `CopyResource` to a DEFAULT resource for actual rendering.

`DYNAMIC` for textures should be reserved for very frequent updates (like say video texture playback), and of course for vertex buffers when doing dynamic draw submission. Constant buffers are really intended to be `DYNAMIC` or use `UpdateSubresource` which really depends on your update pattern (a topic covered in the talk above).

Whenever possible, creating resources as `IMMUTABLE` and with pInitialData is the best option with DirectX 11 as it potentially allows the driver some opportunity for multi-threaded resource creation which is more efficient.

The main thing to be aware of with this pattern is that STAGING resources can result in virtual-memory fragmentation which can be a problem for 32-bit (X86) apps, so you should try to use them rather than creating a lot of them or destroying them and recreating them. See the talk "Why Your Windows Game Won't Run In 2,147,352,576 Bytes" which is attached to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/16/windows-x64.aspx) post.

I'd suggest your initial version would be to try to use `DEAFAULT+UpdateSubresource` and then compare it with a `DEAULT+STAGING+CopyResource` solution because it really heavily depends on your content and code.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some intermediate/advanced books which will discuss advanced techniques, mostly lightning and anim. objects tips?